# UISearchDisplayController results table overlaps UISearchbar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I added `UISearch` Bar and `UISearchDisplayController` to `UINavigationController` with `MapView`. When I start typing in the search bar, results table view overlaps search bar on `iOS 8`. 
On `iOS 7` it's working without any issues: `UISearchBar` moves on top of navigation bar and stays there on results table view.
On `iOS 8` `UISearchBar` does not move on top of navigation bar and results table view overlaps it.

I tried to add searchBar as a subview to `searchResultsTableView` and still no luck

```
func searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch(controller: UISearchDisplayController) {
    let searchBar = controller.searchBar
    let superView = searchBar.superview
    if let tableSuperView = superView as? UITableView {
    } else {
        searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
        controller.searchResultsTableView.addSubview(searchBar)

    }

}
```

It's doing that only in detail view of `UISplitViewController`.

Ended up doing this:

```
func searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch(controller: UISearchDisplayController) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

func searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch(controller: UISearchDisplayController) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Show some relevant code

Comment: I dragged Search Bar and Search Display Controller in storyboard, so there is no code for initializing it. Only method from UISearchDisplayDelegate I'm implementing is searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool, I deleted it and got the same issue.

Comment: Add `UISearch Bar and UISearchDisplayController` as a subview of the tableView.

Comment: Thanks: I was having exactly the same problem (iOS 8 with compact size class) - and this solution works.